# Matching the last word in an URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

The URL looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/?lessoncontent=lesson-003-pinyin
```

I managed to get the last part with this:

```
var url = window.location.href.split("/").pop();
```

So now I got this:

```
?lessoncontent=lesson-003-pinyin
```

Not sure how to get the last part, though (`pinyin`). I want to be able to do if statements with URLs like this:

```
?lessoncontent=lesson-001-pinyin
?lessoncontent=lesson-003-pinyin
?lessoncontent=lesson-002-complete
?lessoncontent=lesson-003-complete
```

(Only taking into account the last word of the URL).

Example:

```
if (match === "pinyin") { //do stuff }
if (match === "complete") { //do stuff }
```

Comment: where's the if statement? You're not being clear

Comment: Strip split and take last?

Comment: You're taking the wrong approach for handling URLs. 1. parse the url  2. get the query string  3. parse the query string 4. look up the value you need from the key value pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split on `-` and take the last element from it.

```
var match = window.location.href.split("-").pop();
if (match === "pinyin") {}  // do stuff 
if (match === "complete") {} // do stuff
```

We are splitting on `-` and then, taking the last element in it by popping it out of the Array.

Answer (score 1):

```
[^-]*$
```

Try this.See demo.You can direclty apply this over the link and get the answer in one step.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/16

```
var re = /[^-]*$/gm;
var str = 'http://www.example.com/?lessoncontent=lesson-003-pinyin';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
(\w+)[&?\/]?$
```

which will work for all sorts of URLs, for example whether there is a URL parameter or not. It will get all the word characters up to a optional trailing `&`, `?`, or `/`. [See Regex 101 Demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/xN2hX0/2)

Answer (score 1):

You may try RegExp:

```
var match = location.search.match(/(\w+)$/)[0]
if (match === "pinyin") { //do stuff }
if (match === "complete") { //do stuff }
```

Here, `location.search` will only the parameters i.e. `?lessoncontent=lesson-001-pinyin`. Next `match(/(\w+)$/)` gives you an array of matching words from the end of string.